# Python download youtube with specific filename

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I'm trying to download youtube videos with `pytube` this way:

```
from pytube import YouTube
YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download()
```

but the file will have the same name as the original video name. How do I specify a custom filename?

Comment: Why not just rename the file after download?

Comment: I think there should be a way to do this ... renaming is not prefered

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

The feature is now added. Do this:

```
YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
    .streams.first()
    .download(filename='filename')
```

**Old answer:**

This is not possible in the current latest (v7.0.18) release. The feature has been added, but no new release has been released since then. If you want to have this feature, you need to download the pytube repository: https://github.com/NFicano/pytube

If you have done so, you can use `YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download(filename='filename')`

It will automatically add the filename extension, so you don't have to include that.

I found it by reading the source. There, I found the declaration of the function `download` in the file `streams.py`:

```
def download(self, output_path=None, filename=None):
```

So you can obviously also specify a path.

For a good workaround, see landogardner's answer.

Answer (score 6):

To add to klutt's answer, it doesn't look like there's been a new pypi release since this feature was added, so for now you can either download the code directly as klutt suggests, or, as a workaround, manually rename the file after the `download()` call, e.g.:

```
import os
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0')
yt.streams.first().download()
os.rename(yt.streams.first().default_filename, 'new_filename.ext')`
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Documentation](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.Stream.download), you can now specify a name for the stream you want to download by using the "filename" argument.

```
download(output_path=[path], filename=[name you want file to be saved as])
```

Answer (score -1):

from pytube import YouTube
//any video link
name = YouTube.YouTube('https://youtu.be/3ZAE7YU8dK8').title
YouTube('http://youtube.com/watchv=9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download(filename = (f'{name}.mp4')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).