# Why do I get HTTP error 410 when trying to download YouTube videos with pytube?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, pytube

I want to download YouTube videos with Python.  I tried opencv with Python, but there was always a problem.  I am trying to use pytube3 and Python 3.  I tried this program (that I found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47649536/python-download-youtube-with-specific-filename)):

```
from pytube import YouTube
YouTube('http://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download()
```

But it failed with the "HTTP Error 410" error.  I keep getting "HTTP Error 410" when I run various pytube programs.  I changed the URL and tested the URLs in a browser.  Nothing works when I run a Python program to download the video.

I am trying to run this program (as I found it [here](https://www.journaldev.com/40720/python-script-to-download-youtube-videos)):

```
from pytube import YouTube
 
try:
    yt_obj = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkU9WFj8sYo')
 
    print(f'Video Title is {yt_obj.title}')
    print(f'Video Length is {yt_obj.length} seconds')
    print(f'Video Description is {yt_obj.description}')
    print(f'Video Rating is {yt_obj.rating}')
    print(f'Video Views Count is {yt_obj.views}')
    print(f'Video Author is {yt_obj.author}')
 
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I got this:

> HTTP Error 410: Gone Traceback (most recent call last):   File "e.py",
> line 9, in 
> yt_obj = YouTube(url)   File "/home/jdoe/path_dir/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/**main**.py",
> line 91, in **init**
> self.prefetch()   File "/home/jdoe/path_dir/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/**main**.py",
> line 181, in prefetch
> self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)   File "/home/jdoe/path_dir/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/request.py",
> line 36, in get
> return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")   File "/home/jdoe/path_dir/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytube/request.py",
> line 24, in _execute_request
> return urlopen(request)  # nosec   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
> response = meth(req, response)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
> response = self.parent.error(   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 563, in error
> result = self._call_chain(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 755, in http_error_302
> return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
> response = meth(req, response)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 640, in http_response
> response = self.parent.error(   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
> return self._call_chain(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 649, in
> http_error_default
> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410:
> Gone
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "e.py", line 14, in 
> raise Exception('Some exception occurred.') Exception: Some exception occurred.

My research says that the 410 error involves a URL being found but then moved.  As the problem happens with different youtube links and different programs, I am at a loss.  How can I avoid getting Error 410 messages when using pytube?

Answer (score 10):

There is a [bug in pytube3](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1076) that results in the 410 error. There is a fix linked from that issue that appears to resolve the problem.  If I install the patched version:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Zeecka/pytube@fix_1060#egg=pytube
```

Then I can fetch information about youtube videos without that error:

```
>>> import pytube
>>> yt = pytube.YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkU9WFj8sYo')
>>> yt.title
'Space Ranger Video Game using FXGL and JavaFX'
```

The fix has been submitted as a [pull request](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/pull/1067). Reading through the discussion it looks like there may still be some unresolved issues.

Comment: That didn't solve for me, unfortunately

Comment: Then you should open a new question, include relevant information about your environment, and include a set of steps and code that reliably reproduces the error.

Comment: Try to upgrade to version 11: `python -m pip install --upgrade pytube`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by

1. Uninstalling pytube,
2. Installing latest pytube (version >12), not sure in which version it was fixed, but it worked for me after installing ver 12.1