# Pytube: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone

Tags: python, http, http-error, pytube

I've been getting this error on several programs for now.
I've tried upgrading pytube, reinstalling it, tried some fixes, changed URLs and code, but nothing seems to work.

```
from pytube import YouTube

#ask for the link from user
link = input("Enter the link of YouTube video you want to download:  ")
yt = YouTube(link)

#Showing details
print("Title: ",yt.title)
print("Number of views: ",yt.views)
print("Length of video: ",yt.length)
print("Rating of video: ",yt.rating)
#Getting the highest resolution possible
ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

#Starting download
print("Downloading...")
ys.download()
print("Download completed!!")
```

and this is the error code:

```
  File "C:\Users\Madjid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\app2.py", line 6, in <module>
    yt = YouTube(link)
  File "C:\Users\Madjid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 91, in __init__
    self.prefetch()
  File "C:\Users\Madjid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 181, in prefetch
    self.vid_info_raw = request.get(self.vid_info_url)
  File "C:\Users\Madjid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 36, in get
    return _execute_request(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  File "C:\Users\Madjid\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 24, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request)  # nosec
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 555, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 747, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "E:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered recently here: [How do I download YouTube videos with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68606981/how-do-i-download-youtube-videos-with-python)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try to upgrade, there is a fix in version 11.0.0:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pytube
```

Comment: pytube doesn't install/upgrade by pip anymore its supported on brew

Comment: I had the same problem and this solution worked for me in May 2023. Many thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If you haven't already, install Git on your PC:
https://git-scm.com/download/win

Then open the command window as admin and install this patch:

```
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/Zeecka/pytube@fix_1060
```

Answer (score 6):

I build mine from start to bottom, and ran into to same issue here are the code and steps.

Code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from sys import argv



link = argv[1]
yt = YouTube(link)



yd = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

yd.download(r'C:/Users/adam/OneDrive/Desktop/video')
```

got error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 410: Gone
```

STEPS:

1. `python -m pip install --upgrade pytube`
2. `python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/pytube/pytube`
3. Ran as ADMIN.

worked fine!

Answer (score 5):

I started a personal project a while ago that downloads YT videos (MP4's), and I ran into the same issue, among others. All of the answers were helpful, but it took like 2-3 of them *combined* to resolve my issue:

First, I had to download Git For Windows: (https://git-scm.com/download/win)
Then, I **downgraded** my already installed PyTube package with the below command. This installs PyTube 10.9.3:

```
`python -m pip install git+https://github.com/Zeecka/pytube@fix_1060`
```

Finally, I re-installed the latest version of PyTube (this command installs the **latest version**):

```
`pip install --upgrade pytube`
```

Not sure exactly, what causes PyTube to flip out when you first install, but downgrading, then upgrading worked for me.

For any wondering, final-product code is as seen below. Videos downloaded at 720p, with their title as the name of the saved file.

```
from pytube import YouTube 
  
#where to save 
SAVE_PATH = "C:/YOUR/DESIRED/FILE/PATH/" 
  
#link of the video to be downloaded 
link = input("Enter URL >> ")
try:
    yt = YouTube(link)
    mp4_files = yt.streams.filter(file_extension="mp4")
    mp4_720p_files = mp4_files.get_by_resolution("720p")
    mp4_720p_files.download(SAVE_PATH) 
except Exception as e: 
    print("ERROR: ", e)
```

Sources:

HTTP Error 410 'Gone' - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rrRuBrUrnCw

Git for Windows - https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: I had the same problem and of all the things I tested, this was what did it for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks bro nothing worked for me. Except for your answer. (i downgraded to pytube10.9.3)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug of the pytube version. You might install an older version of it. Upgrade pytube to 11+ will resolve the issue.

- Open the terminal and execute the following command to upgrade the version

  ```
  pip install --upgrade pytube
  ```

[image]

https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1243

Answer (score 1):

**How I solved the error**

1. First uninstall your pytube using pip

   pip uninstall pytube
2. Clear pip cache

   pip cache purge
3. Install pytube again

   pip install pytube

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest version from the official GitHub repository
https://github.com/pytube/pytube

```
python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/pytube/pytube
```

[Updated to pytube 11.0.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kBO1.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this because the solutions I found on the internet didn't work for me (the ones above too).

I even tried to install an other fix done ssuwani on GitHub using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ssuwani/pytube
```

(I use python 3.8.10 and Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS)

I just used `sudo su` to enter admin mode, ran my program and it worked. To be honest, I don't know why, but if it can help that's nice :)

Warning, don't enter any commands when you're in admin mode because you could mess up your system

Answer (score 0):

Open CommandPrompt/Powershell or your OS equivalent as an 'Administrator':

1. Uninstall the pytube library using (pip uninstall pytube)
2. Clear the environment cache memory (pip cache purge)
3. Install pytube again (pip install pytube).